# divert yarn add to different path without --cwd

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I have a project with root folder and client folder, both having `package.json` files.

On the root folder I don't want to install any packages, ever. Instead, I want that running `$ yarn add some-package` will automatically add it in the client folder, as if I would do `$ yarn add some-package --cwd ./client`

I tried doing `cd client` and `yarn --cwd ./client` in `scripts.preinstall`, but it didn't work, which I think it's because `preinstall` and `install` are different processes.

I also tried running a cusotm bash script on `preinstall` but didn't find a way to pass the args from the command line to it, so they get "swollen" by yarn.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

I'm fairly new with bash, but I can research the solution with some guidance.

Thanks in advance, make it a great day!

PS. I can hack it by hijacking the yarn command on my shell, and check if I'm ot the aforementioned project folder and if the command was `yarn add`, but I prefer to have a solution for all our developers, and not to pollute my shell.

Comment: Why not use symlink for the `node_modules`, `package.json` to the client folder from the root folder?

Comment: I need an empty `yarn.lock` file on the root for heroku, and  `client/yarn.lock` to be valid. How would that work with symlink?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use a `.yarnrc` file in your root project folder next to your `package.json`.

Add this line to `.yarnrc`:

```
# install modules in the specified location
--modules-folder ./client
```

Note: If you already have a `node_modules` folder feel free to delete it after creating `.yarnrc` and follow it by running `yarn install` for all your packages to be downloaded again into your target directory.

Comment: That resolves the node_modules location, but the `yarn.lock` file should be in client folder as well. Like I said in the comment to my question: *I need an empty yarn.lock file on the root for heroku, and client/yarn.lock to be valid*

Comment: Try with `--cwd ./client` instead of `--modules-folder`. Try both also if needed, see if it works @goldylucks

Comment: yarnrc doesn't take --cwd :/